# Ping Raspberry Pi from another computer on the same network

Tags: windows, networking, raspberry-pi

I have set up an ad hoc network between two laptops. One of the laptops is connected directly to the Raspberry Pi via Ethernet. This laptop can ping and SSH into the Raspberry Pi just fine. How do I get the second laptop to be able to ping the Raspberry Pi?

The IP of the Raspberry Pi is 192.168.137.99, the Ethernet ipv4 address of the laptop connected to the Pi is 192.168.137.1, and I have set the address of the Wireless LAN adapter Wi-fi on the second laptop as 192.168.137.2. The second laptop can ping 192.168.137.1, but not 192.168.137.99 (destination host unreachable). The first laptop (192.168.137.1) cannot ping 192.168.137.2, it says destination host unreachable. The subnet masks are all 255.255.255.0. I am pretty new to this so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people use routers for that. Get a home router, ensure it has DHCP server on, connect all 3 devices to the router however you want (with cable or wifi), setup the devices to use automatic IP address, they’ll get 3 IP addresses from the router’s DHCP server, and you’ll be able to ping them however you want.

If you don’t have a router or don’t want to use it, there’s another option. You can setup the laptop that has Pi connected to act as a network bridge. [Here’s how.](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10) This way this laptop will route these IP packets between your 2 network (one Ethernet with the Pi, another one WiFi with your second laptop). Because it will be no DHCP server on your network, you’ll have to setup IP addresses manually. Make sure all 3 devices use different IP addresses from the same subnet, 192.168.137.* with mask 255.255.255.0 should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! The bridging solution was exactly what I was looking for since I don't want to use a router.